# Asynchronous method runs synchronously c#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to write an asynchronous method to just execute some logic for a set of dates between a larger set of dates, but it's not running asynchronous. I'm trying to do logic on dates between `startDate` and `endDate`, but in chunks of 5 or less if there is less than 5 days to calculate.

So from `6-1-2018` to `6-29-2018` there are a total of 5 chunks to do logic on. I'm trying to fire off an asynchronous method for each chunk at the same time.

The total time to execute each should be around 5 seconds since the task is just sleeping for 5 seconds. It's currently running for 30 seconds which means it's **not** asynchronous, but synchronous. How can I fix it so I can run each of these operations asynchronously?

```
public async static void Foo()
{
    var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

    DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2018, 6, 29);
    int dayIntervals = 4; // Query 5 days at a time

    for (DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2018, 6, 1); startDate.Date <= endDate.Date; startDate = startDate.AddDays(dayIntervals + 1))
    {
        dayIntervals = (startDate.AddDays(dayIntervals) > endDate ? dayIntervals = endDate.Day - startDate.Day : dayIntervals);
        tasks.Add(Action(startDate, startDate.AddDays(dayIntervals))); // Add the tasks
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks); // Fire them asynchronously?
    watch.Stop();
    var elapsed = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds).TotalSeconds;

    Debug.WriteLine("Finished in: " + elapsed + " seconds"); // 30 sec
}

public static Task<DataTable> Action(DateTime one, DateTime two)
{
    // Junk related to the table to be returned
    // ...

    Random r = new Random();
    Thread.Sleep(5000);

    return Task.FromResult(table);
}
```

Comment: Use `await Task.Delay` instead of `Thread.Sleep`.

Comment: You don't have any asynchronous code.

Comment: But wouldn't these be all on running on their own thread? What's the point of it running `async` if it's all on one thread.

Comment: First, you don't have any asynchronous code. Second, asynchronous does not mean parallel. You need to read the basics on async and await.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/

Comment: Did you read the all msdn comments : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160374(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Task.FromResult means *you already have your result, and therefore the time it takes to calculate it has already been spent*. You should look at a TCS https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 or return Task.Run(() => GenerateResultLol());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Action` method isn't asynchronous. It doesn't `await` anything.

Replace the synchronous call to `Thread.Sleep` with `await Task.Delay`.

Once you include an `await`, the compiler will force you to declare it as **async**:

```
public static async Task<DataTable> Action(DateTime one, DateTime two)
```

Comment: Keyword should be `async`, but it's too few characters for me to suggest an edit. Also note you can't bold text inside a code block.